# Cant start RabbitMQ server: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtinfo.6.dylib

Tags: rabbitmq, conda, dyld

I installed RabbitMQ from conda (`Miniconda3-4.5.4-MacOSX-x86_64`):

```
$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
$ bash Miniconda3-4.5.4-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -b -p conda
$ export PATH=${PWD}/conda/bin:${PATH}
$ conda install -c conda-forge rabbitmq-server=3.7.13

$ which rabbitmq-server
/Users/username/projects/myapp/conda/bin/rabbitmq-server
```

When I try to run it, I get errors like this:

```
$ rabbitmq-server
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtinfo.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/projects/myapp/conda/lib/erlang/erts-10.3/bin/beam.smp
  Reason: image not found
/Users/username/projects/myapp/conda/lib/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 201: 52785 Abort trap: 6           NOTIFY_SOCKET= RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=$RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE ERL_CRASH_DUMP=$ERL_CRASH_DUMP RABBITMQ_CONFIG_ARG_FILE=$RABBITMQ_CONFIG_ARG_FILE RABBITMQ_DIST_PORT=$RABBITMQ_DIST_PORT ${ERL_DIR}erl -pa "$RABBITMQ_EBIN_ROOT" -boot "${CLEAN_BOOT_FILE}" -noinput -hidden -s rabbit_prelaunch ${RABBITMQ_NAME_TYPE} ${RABBITMQ_PRELAUNCH_NODENAME} -conf_advanced "${RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE}" -rabbit enabled_plugins_file "\"$RABBITMQ_ENABLED_PLUGINS_FILE\"" -rabbit plugins_dir "\"$RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR\"" -extra "${RABBITMQ_NODENAME}"

$ rabbitmqctl status
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtinfo.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/projects/myapp/conda/lib/erlang/erts-10.3/bin/beam.smp
  Reason: image not found
```

Any idea what is going on? Nothing on Google has helped. I am running on macOS Sierra 10.12.6. I have seen a lot of guides say to use Homebrew for this but I would really rather stick with conda, since I am deploying with conda on other servers.

Comment: While I don't think this is necessarily the issue, you should be aware that adding `*conda/bin` to your `PATH` is no longer recommended (see [Conda v4.4 Release Notes](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was an answer listed here: https://github.com/conda-forge/fish-feedstock/issues/14#issuecomment-430807396

> Your issue looks very similar to [conda-forge/tmux-feedstock#12](https://github.com/conda-forge/tmux-feedstock/issues/12). I see
>   in your package list that you also have ncurses from the default
>   channel. Does conda install conda-forge::ncurses fix this error?

Running this before installing anything else fixed the error:

```
conda install conda-forge::ncurses
```